# An analysis of analysis?

Tags: statistics

This is perhaps not an ideal question by StackExchange rules, but I don't know where to find a more informed community, so I'll attempt to make it as specific as possible.

I'm trying to wrap my brain around 'data analysis', and I'm looking for attempts to analyze the field, to perhaps create a taxonomy of the analytic process, or in some other way to impose an order on 'analysis', where analysis might include both descriptive and predictive modeling.

In the field of data graphics, there are several well known examples: One could look at *Visualizing Data* by Cleveland, in which he organizes graphical techniques by dimensionality, or more broadly, at Bertin's *Semiology of Graphics*, or Wilkinson's *The Grammar of Graphics*.

In a related domain (a sub-domain of analysis, actually), Codd's relational algebra attempts to organize the filtering and summarization of tabular data. (I'm very much focused on tabular data.)

What I'm asking for are pointers to a proposed "grammar" of analytics.

Comment: From my experience, different people tend to mean a broad range of different things when they use the term "data analysis". You already hinted at your particular interest ("I'm very much focused on tabular data."), and you might benefit from further narrowing down which particular meaning of "data analysis" you have in mind.